# Unclear how to login to (or JOIN) a stack exchange site I haven't joined yet

Tags: bug, android-app

I am logged in on my android app.

I followed a link from reddit to an `apple.stackexchange.com` question and I wanted to cast a vote.

A slide out red message appeared stating:

> The account associated with the access_token does not have a user on the site

Is there a way to create a user on a site from the app? Should it be easy to get to following a no user on site error?